# setting interval for notifications

Tags: coffeescript, setinterval

The following coffeeScript is running properly *without* the references to `setUpdateInterval`.

```
class Notifications
  constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
    @setup() if @notifications.length > 0
    setUpdateInterval()

  setup: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->
      "<li class='active'><a href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.actor} #{notification.notifiable.type}</a></li>"

    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)

    setUpdateInterval: (notifications) ->
      callback = @setup.bind(this)
      setInterval( callback, 15000 )

jQuery ->
  new Notifications
```

What is incorrect with the additional line and bloc inserted?

Comment: `setUpdateInterval` is *inside* `handleSuccess` so `handleSuccess` is returning `{setUpdateInterval: function....}`. Also, `setUpdateInterval()` is trying to call a global function, `@setUpdateInterval()` would call the method (if there was such a method of course).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment, the following functions.

```
  constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
    @setUpdateInterval()
    @setup() if @notifications.length > 0

  setup: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  setUpdateInterval: (notifications) ->
      callback = @setup.bind(this)
      setInterval( callback, 15000 )
```